# Solving a system of generated equations?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, code-request

I would like to generate a function in the following form, where the number of terms can be specified arbitrarily:

```
(* cVal[1] + cVal[2] x + cVal[3] x^2 + cVal[4] x^3 *)
```

I've tried things along this line:

```
cList = Block[{n = 1}, Table[cVal[i], {i, 2 (n + 1)}]]

(* {cVal[1], cVal[2], cVal[3], cVal[4]} *)

xList = Block[{n = 1}, Table[x^(i - 1), {i, 2 (n + 1)}]]

(* {1, x, x^2, x^3} *)

cList.xList

(* cVal[1] + x cVal[2] + x^2 cVal[3] + x^3 cVal[4] *)
```

Is there a better way to construct this result from `cList.xList` ? I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
y[x_] := cList.xList
```

Since the length of y should change in my program if I change the value of n, how would I go about making this into a function of x?

So I want a function

```
y[x_] := cVal[1] + cVal[2] x + cVal[3] x^2 + cVal[4] x^3
```

and then it's derivative with respect to x would be

```
y'[x_] := cVal[2]  + 2 cVal[3] x + 3 cVal[4] x^2
```

Now given the following conditions (for n=1, 4 conditions are necessary, more conditions would be needed if n is increased), say

```
y[0] = r; y'[0] = S; y[1] = t; y'[1] = u;
```

I would like to solve for the cVal's. For this case, to solve for  cVal[1], cVal[2], cVal[3], cVal[4]. So notice that for y[0]=r, which means x=0, then plugging that in gives that cVal[1] = r and so on.

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong, or suggest a better approach?

Comment: `y[x_,n_]:=Array[c,n].x^Range[0,2*n+1]` might be a start on what you want.

Comment: Should the solve part be automated? If so it's quite tricky.

Answer (score 2):

```
c[n_?IntegerQ] := Array[cVal, 2 n + 2, 0]                  (* Unknowns *)
y[n_?NumericQ, x1_] := c[n].x^Range[0, 2 n + 1] /. x -> x1 (*function  value*)
dy[n_?NumericQ, x1_] := D[y[n, x], x] /. x -> x1           (*derivative*)

(*Now the solving function*)
res[n_, pts_, vals_] := 
            Solve[Flatten@
                  MapThread[{y[n, #1] == #2[[1]], dy[n, #1] == #2[[2]]} &, {pts, vals}],
                  c@n]

(*Usage*)
pts = {x1, x2};                 (*x values*)
vals = {{y1, dy1}, {y2, dy2}};  (*function and derivative for each x value*)
res[1, pts, vals] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

But please note that your system is linear and can be solved with `LinearSolve[ ]`:

```
y[n_?NumericQ]  := x^Range[0, 2 n + 1]   (*function*)
dy[n_?NumericQ] := D[y[n], x]            (*derivative*)
mat[n_, pts_]   := Flatten[{y[n], dy[n]} /. # & /@ Thread[x -> pts], 1]

(* Usage *)    
pts  = {x1, x2};                       (*x values*)
vals = {{y1, dy1}, {y2, dy2}};         (*function and derivative for each x value*)
LinearSolve[mat[1, pts], Flatten@vals] // Together
```